# Memory in SQLDB chain

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, langchain, conversational-ai

I want to know , if we can you memory in SQL DB chain
`db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain(llm=llm, database=db, verbose=True)`

Can we introduce Coversational Buffer memory in this ?
If not is there any alternative way to achieve this ?

I tried introducing the memory in SQL DB chain like this :
`db_chain = SQLDatabaseChainWithMemory.from_llm(llm, db, verbose=True, memory=memory)`

using a custom class :

```
from langchain import SQLDatabaseChain
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory

class SQLDatabaseChainWithMemory(SQLDatabaseChain):
    def __init__(self, \*args, memory: ConversationBufferWindowMemory, \*\*kwargs):
        super().__init__(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
        self.memory = memory

    def run(self, inputs):
        # Add the memory variables to the inputs
        inputs_with_memory = {**inputs, **self.memory.load_memory_variables({})}
        
        # Call the parent class's run method with the updated inputs
        return super().run(inputs_with_memory)
```

It was able to store the query like this
{'query': 'what is the county name at zip code 7643 ',
'memory': [HumanMessage(content='...... ', additional_kwargs={}, example=False),
AIMessage(content='Final answer: .......', additional_kwargs={}, example=False)],
'result': 'Final answer here: .......'}

But is was not able to answer the question based on history .

I doubt that memory is not avaiable for SQLDB chain .

Comment: Can anyone suggest a workaround, perhaps , using an agent along with the chain .